# Cant open Output File .exe in Codeblocks IDE

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Whenever I compiled my C++ program in codeblocks ide, it runs but after once it show error that

**"cannot open output file C:\Users\AkM\Desktop\code\g1.exe Invalid argument|" .**

I had tried killing process(.exe file) from Task Manager, opening and closing codeblocks but same things happen all the time.

Please help, it really creates trouble for me while coding. This happens with almost every C++ program.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>  
using namespace std;

 int main()
{

    int n ,m,k;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

    int l = n + m;
    vector<int>vec[l];
    int x,y;
    for(int i =0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin >> x>>y;
        vec[x].push_back(y);
        vec[y].push_back(x);
    }
    cout << vec[1][3]  << endl;
    vector<int >vv;
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<vec[i].size();j++)
        {
          v.push_back(vec[i][j]);
          cout << "hello" << endl;
          cout << vec[i][j]<<" ";
          cout << "hello" << endl;
        cout << "hello" << endl;
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end(),greater<int>());
        if(v.size()>k)
        {
            vv.push_back(1);
        }
        else
        {cout << "hello" << endl;
            vv.push_back(v[k-1]);
        }
        v.clear();
        cout << endl;
    }
    for(int i =0;i<vv.size();i++)
    cout << vv[i] << endl;
}
```

[ERROR LINK  :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2TaM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common error on IDE and modern systems. Most of the time, when you run a program, the executable file is kept open by the running program, and this is enough to prevent changes to the file => the link phase cannot complete.
The normal solution is just to ensure to close any running instance of the program before a build.

When there is a crash in a program launched from the IDE, the IDE can open the process in debug mode to allow the programmer to see what could have happened. In that case you must close that debug session before a new build.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and by default it will create a main.cpp file in the project. Try to build the project and see if you face errors. If you don't see any error, replace the main.cpp contents with your code and build the project again. It did not result in runtime error for me and a console opened when I ran your program.

Comment: Found the problem ..
Whenever my program gives runtime problem **pr.exe stop working** in that case this problem occurs i think.
I just write 2 more programs with such problems (accessing invalid index in array) face the same.
It might be due to this only.